# mySQL doesn't start in XAMPP on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, mysql, xampp

I installed XAMPP. Apache is getting active but when I try MySQL, it doesn't start. I will appreciate if someone can help me.

Looks like RC=0 but it doesn't do anything. It gives the following messages.

```
6:48:36 PM  [mysql]       Attempting to start MySQL service...
6:48:36 PM  [mysql]       Executing "net start "mysql""
6:48:36 PM  [mysql]       Return code: 0
```